# Radio button freezes/disabled on checking

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I am working on an angular project and have developed an application which needs to be compatible with iPad the problem is in with radio button whenever it is clicked it freezes/disabled in Safari and works fine every where else in chrome Mozilla etc . I was looking for a suggestion which can help me solve this bug thanks in advance

Comment: You can find the compatibility of your methods from this site.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio

Answer (score 1):

We can't judge if we don't see the code. But generally speaking in those kind of problems, there's some functions that are not supported by some browsers. 
So either you gotta find an equivalent function supported by all targeted's browsers, or rewrite the code in an another manner.